# Setting values of multidimensional array on "Dim" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

In VBA I can set the values of a multidimensional array this way:

```
mArr = [{"1", "Hello"; "World",  "I"; "am", "Sam"}]
```

How can I do this in vb.net?

I mean something like (not working):

```
Dim mArr() As String From  [{"1", "Hello"; "World",  "I"; "am", "Sam"}]
```

Comment: @wahwahwah [don't you mean this page?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sxy840k(v=vs.90).aspx) Downvote reason: Your question shows no effort what so ever to find the answer yourself. please rtfm, and I mean that in the nicest way possible.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - yes. Deleted my other comment.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, I know it's my fault, but I'm trying since yesterday and I've made many attempts before posting the question. I don't speak english so well and so I was not able to search with right words.

Comment: @genespos - i think you meant that message for Zohar. I just posted a link (actually, a bad one at that) - I didn't downvote. Best of luck.

Comment: Don't appoligize, just take it as a leason for the next questions and show your efforts in the question itself. I can assure you that if you would have written this into your question I would not have downvoted it. In fact, if you can edit your question so that it reflect your efforts then I will be able to retract my downvote.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm not worried about the downvote I only want to say that I respect who spend his time to solve other people's problems.

Comment: Well, to many people, the best way to learn things is to explain them to others. Also, all of us started the the exact same knowledge - 0. Every single programmer I know (and know of) have had questions answered by more experienced programmers, whether it's on stackoverflow or on some other website. You can probably help other programmers yourself if you have the time. I appreciate your respect, and respect you for having that respect.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Your first sentence is very true for me. I only learnt how to make a good research after trying to help other on this site. Now, I rarely need the help of others, since most of the times, I can sort out my problem by myself and the help of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it as:

```
Dim values(,) As String =
    New String(,) {{"1", "Hello"},
           {"World", "I"},
           {"am", "Sam"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little research would go along way...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sxy840k(v=vs.90).aspx

```
Dim startingScores(,) As Short = New Short(1, 1) {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}
```